# Redirect a form to an external URL

Tags: forms, 8, redirection

Want to redirect $form_state to external URL after successful registration of the user. Like, need to redirect to facebook after user registration.

```
  $query = "http://facebook.com";
  $url = Url::fromRoute('user.register', [], ['query' => ['service' => $query]]);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url); 
  //$url = Url::fromUri($query); 
  return RedirectResponse::create($url->toString(), 302); 

  $form_state>setResponse(newTrustedRedirectResponse('https://google.com', 302)); 
  return new RedirectResponse($query); 
  $form_state->setRedirect($query); 
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri($query));
  $response = new RedirectResponse($query); 
  $response->send();
```

tried above all methods, but nothing works.

Comment: You should use `setRedirectUrl` and `Url::fromUri('http://facebook.com', ['absolute' => TRUE]);` per the API docs for Url::fromUri.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method that you missed is [`$form_state->setResponse()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetResponse/8.2.x). In combination with a [`TrustedRedirectResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21TrustedRedirectResponse.php/class/TrustedRedirectResponse/8.2.x) object, which exists for security reasons (to prevent users from accidentally being redirected to another site), you can use code similar to the following.

```
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://facebook.com');
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```